# Logic error creating DIV grid with CSS and PHP

Tags: php, css, html, logic

I am having trouble figuring out the logic in creating a grid using DIVs.  3 Columns (the **$count** variable), then fill those columns with however many boxes. (**$totalBoxes**)

Below is an example of what I would like to accomplish. 
[image]

I have tried using logic on repeated regions for tables, but I don’t know if that is working right. Most of my code spits out something like this screenshot: 
[image]

Can someone point me where my logic is wrong?

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {
background-color: #FFC;
height: 750px;
width: 900px;
padding: 5px;
}
#container #column {
background-color: #FC6;
width: 200px;
padding: 5px;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
}
#container #column #box {
background-color: #9C3;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
margin: 5px;
}
</style>
```

**PHP**

```
<div id="container">
  <?php 
$count = 3;
$totalBoxes = 8;
?>
  <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalBoxes; $i++) {

if ($i % $count == 1){ ?>
<div id="column"> Column <?php echo $i; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<div id="box"> <?php echo $i; ?> </div>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `$count` the number of columns desired?

Comment: Yes, it is the number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in else thread because you have two closing divs in it.
Also you can't have repeated `id`

I can't understand do you want 3 columns or 3 rows? If you want 3 columns that your code will not work on `totalBoxes` mote than 9 (it will produce more columns).

I suggest you to use following logic:

```
<style>
    .column {float: left; padding: 10px; width: 100px; border: solid thin red; background-color: green; margin-right: 5px}
    .box {width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color: white; margin-bottom: 5px; }
</style>
<?php
$boxes_in_column = ceil($totalBoxes / 3);
echo('<div class="column">Column 1');
for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalBoxes; $i++) {
    echo('<div class="box">'.$i.'</div>');
    if (($i % $boxes_in_column) === 0){
        echo('</div><div class="column">Column '.(ceil($i / $boxes_in_column)+1));
    }
}
echo('</div>');
?>
```

It will produce extra empty column if you have total boxes divided by 3 without remainder. So try to fix it yourself.

[image: three columns]

Horizontal fill

```
<style>
  .box1 {display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: white; margin: 5px; }
  .parent {background-color: blue; border: solid thin red; width: 330px}
</style>

<?php
$totalBoxes = 13;

echo '<div class="parent">';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalBoxes; $i++) {
    echo('<div class="box1">'.$i.'</div>');
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

[image: horizontal fill]

Comment: I want 3 columns. But i want to fill the columns with however many boxes is necessary. The closing div is the matching div for the column div.

Comment: i edited my answer and added sample code,  it can be typos, i haven't tested it.

Comment: yes, you're right, that closing div is for column BUT it will close your column right after first iteration. Check out your HTML code produced. Also you will never get Column1, Column2, Column3 with that code because `$i` increases with boxes.

Comment: Just tested — works like a charm. Updated code with styles. You can test it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I see I should have added another column div in loop!

Comment: Any thoughts on altering it keep the columns the same, but instead of filling the left one up first and moving to the second column, you put one box in the first, box 2 in the 2nd column, box 3 in the 3 and box 4 in the first etc..

Comment: You can just add `display: inline-block;` for .box and set fixed width for parent container to fit exact 3 boxes and than just echo your boxes in loop. So you don't need a <div class="column"> anymore.

Comment: i added sample in my answer